# jQuery Fancybox destroys layout

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I've got a site where I use fancybox. When the contents of the fancybox is higher than about 500 pixels, there comes a big white area beneath the footer of my page. When I restrict the height to about 500 pixels (or even lower), there still appears such an area. How can I solve this?

```
/* Fancybox Code on page */
jQuery('.dialog').fancybox({titleShow:false,type:'inline'});

/* HTML Code on page */
<a href="display-page.html" class="dialog">Display page</a>
```

And this is what the page inside the fancybox looks like:

```
/* Display-page.html: Code that's displayed (ajax), this page has no body/head/<html>/doctype */
/* See also http://jsfiddle.net/E358Q/ */
<div style="width: 800px;"><!-- content over here --></div>
```

Comment: Posting your page markup and jQuery code would probably help.

Comment: So I did, this is the code. (after the edit)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the complete markup, including what's inside the `<div>`. An editable demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be best, of course :)

Comment: @Kevin, sorry, your fiddle doesn't work. `$(".dialog")` doesn't even match anything. Did you paste the wrong HTML?

Comment: No, the HTML is the page INSIDE fancybox, outside it's just the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with my sticky footer. No solution for this problem so far. Maybe I should try another lightbox instead of fancybox to see if that one will work.